# Problem using "zrevrange" and "scale reads: slaves" on ioredis

Tags: redis, amazon-elasticache, ioredis

We are currently using "ioredis" adapter for nodejs.
Some of our logic is calling a none clustered redis, we would like to scale our calls using "scale reads" attribute that sends commands to the "replicas" to reduce load from the primary node.

The problem is that the most common command we use and we would like to scale is "zrevrange", and it's simply not calling the replicas.

ioredis version: 2.5.0,
the redis we are using is on AWS ElastiCache engine version: 3.2.4

Answer (score 0):

IORedis do not support scale reads on non clustered redis.